# Problems implementing memcpy

Tags: rust

I'm working on a project that uses `libcore` and `no_std`, this requires an implementation of various memory manipulation functions. However, when I try to implement memcpy,

```
#[no_mangle]
#[no_stack_check]
pub unsafe extern fn memcpy(dest: *mut u8, src: *const u8, n: usize) -> *mut u8{
    for i in 0..n {
        *dest.offset(i as isize) = *src.offset(i as isize);
    }
    return dest;
}
```

I get

```
error: expected ident, found `*`
*dest.offset(i as isize) = *src.offset(i as isize);
^
```

Comment: Can you the result from `rustc --version` to the question? I couldn't reproduce your error locally.

Comment: This code also compiles [on the playpen](http://is.gd/NF4K4w). Side note, you should probably remove the `return` statement to be more idiomatic.

Comment: rustc 1.0.0-dev (73a25f55a 2015-01-09 20:10:07 +0000)

Comment: rust grammar regarding ranges improved since your version.

Comment: word, I'm currently building master, so I figure that will help.

Comment: Do you know about [`rlibc`](https://crates.io/crates/rlibc)? It implements the memory functions `core` needs. Also, I believe the approach of implementing `memcpy` naively will cause infinite recursion (a bad interaction between rustc and LLVM), while `rlibc` is careful to avoid this.

Comment: I'm aware, my implementation has feature parity. The bit of code I posted can be found almost unchanged in rlibc. I built master and my builds started working so I think it was just an issue with the version of rust I had.